# How to get redirected urls on a headless server

Tags: selenium, redirect, headless-browser

Please suggest a method of getting final urls after redirection in an automated way. It has to run on my headless Ubuntu server.

Selenium will only start a browser in headless mode on this server, else error:

```
opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
```

But this way the .current_url method on a webdriver instance does not get the redirect, whereas on my PC with normal display mode I am getting the redirect correctly.

Solving this with tools other than Selenium would be great, too.

Comment: Can't you use `requests` module ? `r = requests.get(url)` then `print(r.url)` ? I think Selenium is too overpowered and slow for just get final url... By default requests follow redirections

Comment: It returns the original url. Maybe it's something to do with the webpage, because both headless Selenium and requests return only the original url. "http://www.stylight.co.uk/redirect.action?productUuid=6bcc5272-2535-505e-b3a6-02a8fdbe5b43&view=display&campaignId=17111&utm_source=criteo&utm_medium=display&utm_content=RTB UK&utm_campaign=17111&source=7"

Comment: Hum be careful they protect their page, I think with curl and requests AND selenium headless your are detected as a bot : `As you were browsing www.stylight.co.uk something about your browser made us think you were a bot.`. but if you manage to bypass this security (http headers or something) you may have 302/301 redirect OR html redirection OR js redirection.